# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Intel HD 630 and nvidia RTX2060 fails to load the Intel driver

Tags: drivers, intel

I have a system with two graphics cards. The integrated one (Intel 630) and an nVidia.
Monitor is connected to Intel HDMI port.
My aim is to have the PC display(Ubuntu desktop etc..) on Intel and dedicate the nVidia card for CUDA operatations.

nVidia works fine.
Ubuntu desktop is getting displayed but its performance is poor. Video playback flickers and the CPU gets immediately hogged. Its apparent that the driver for intel card fails to be loaded thus the video processing goes to CPU.

On system details, I see:
`Graphics: llvmpipe (LLVM 9.0, 256 bits)` - which confirms the above suspicion.

Hardware seems to be correctly recognized:

```
$ lspci | egrep 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f08 (rev a1)

$ sudo lshw -c video

  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:130 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:df000000-df07ffff

  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 630
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:127 memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

$ sudo prime-select intel
Info: the intel profile is already set
```

Everyone pretty much suggests that the Intel driver should be automatically installed by Ubuntu.
Seems that this is not the case.
Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: The Intel driver is being loaded... "driver=i915".

Comment: Ok any clues why llvmpipe is used then?

Comment: Is `Secure Boot` disabled in your BIOS? Show me `uname -r`. Show me `grep GRUB_CMD /etc/default/grub`. What version Nvidia driver, and did you install it from `Software & Updates/Additional Drivers` or the Nvidia web site?

Comment: Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208354/ubuntu-18-04-4-uses-llvmpipe-instead-of-intel-radeon-hd-8750m and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1276966/ubuntu-20-04-lts-llvmpipe-llvm-10-0-0-256-bits-used-instead-of-nvidia-graph and https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/external-monitor-undetected-in-ubuntu-18-04-inspiron-5593-nvidia-geforce-mx230/107871

Comment: "Is Secure Boot disabled in your BIOS?" : Yes

uname -r : 5.4.0-66-generic

grep GRUB_CMD /etc/default/grub: 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

Nvidia Driver: Says "using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-460(open source)" in Software&Updates-->Additional Drivers. Driver was downloaded from nvidia website
Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the references, i checked all of them. None worked. purging the ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers didnt do any good, my monitor gets normally detected and i updated grub as instructed and rebooted with no effect. LLvmpipe remains.

Comment: Let's try a quick test. Edit /etc/default/grub and change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"`, then `sudo update-grub`, then `reboot`. The video modes will be limited, but I just want to see if llvmpipe is gone (when your monitor is connected to the Intel).

Comment: Just tried this, the machine never managed to boot. I fell into a very similar issue described in https://askubuntu.com/questions/826622/booting-problem-ubuntu-gnome-16-04-01-lts. For now i just reverted grub and rebooted. Will try to purge and reinstall nvidia drivers as described in the article the soonest.

Comment: Tried to purge and reinstall nvidia and xserver-xorg - no good. If there are no more suggestions i will have to reinstall Ubuntu unfortunately.

Comment: Reinstall Ubuntu